# Drivers PDO do PHP para SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, driver

Estava com o mesmo problema, realizei os passos indicados, porém, não tive sucesso na instalação da conexão SQL Server.

Versões:

- PHP = 5.6.21;
- SO = Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise SP1.

Instalei os seguintes componentes:

- Cópia das DLLs para a pasta ext do php: php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll e php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll (meu php está para Thread Safety conforme DLL "php5ts.dll");
- Adicionei no arquivo "php.ini" as extensões: "extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll" e "extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll";
- Na imagem abaixo, é possível notar que a extensão no foi habilitada.
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se alguém conseguir me ajudar.

Comment: No seu script que testa conexão, adicione essa linha `ini_set('display_startup_errors', true);` deve exibir algum erro.

Comment: Qual é a mensagem?

Comment: PDOException: could not find driver in C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\API\conexao.php on line 10.

Comment: Esta foi a mensagem... porém como eu disse na pergunta, já copiei os arquivos para a pasta "ext", configurei no arquivo "php.ini" e reiniciei o vertrigo.

Comment: Outras exetensões vc instala sem problemas?

Comment: Essa "php_pdo_odbc.dll" eu consegui instalar. Até achei que eu deveria ativar ela também, porém, pelos tutoriais que li não precisa.